# How to import and use .so file

Tags: go, gccgo

Please give me example (code) how to import into main.go a .so file made gccgo?

Answer (score 1):

Go does not yet support dynamic code loading (i.e. plugins).  There are plans to add support in the future, but no set time table at this point:

https://docs.google.com/document/d/1nr-TQHw_er6GOQRsF6T43GGhFDelrAP0NqSS_00RgZQ/preview

Answer (score 0):

You can't dynamically load Go "dlls", yet.