# Is there possibility to use .so files?

Tags: go, cgo

Such similar question was posted 6 yrs ago
([How to import and use .so file in golang program](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26536556/how-to-import-and-use-so-file-in-golang-program))

I guess the current releases would have looked into this.

I have to call network.so from my Go code.

**One of the function under network.so**

```
bool Tape::test1(obj a,obj b) {
}
```

**My current implementation**

```
/* #cgo LDFLAGS: -ldl
 #include <dlfcn.h>
*/

func main() {
   handle := C.dlopen(C.CString("network.so"), C.RTLD_LAZY)
   //How to call C.test1 function ? 
}
```

Looking for some examples.

Comment: Here's [a library](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/coreos/pkg/dlopen) that abstracts over `dlopen`. And see some [github code](https://github.com/search?l=Go&q=dlopen&type=Code) on using it. If you prefer using `C.dlopen` directly, see [some source code](https://sourcegraph.com/search?q=C.dlopen+lang%3Ago&patternType=literal) doing exactly that.

Comment: @thwd, thank you. Will look into this

Comment: Have look at this https://golang.hotexamples.com/examples/c/-/dlopen/golang-dlopen-function-examples.html

Comment: Do you have to use dlopen? Can you just link the library at compile time?