# Calling CPython extension from Go

Tags: python, go, swig

I currently have a source files written in C++ and wrapped into a Python module (uses Boost and Parser libs).

I ported the C++ folder under go/src and .so files along with main.go

**Program Structure**

```
src
   /main
      main.go
      network.so
   /network
       file1.cpp (this has a function **object DBdata::getTable())
       file1.hpp (#define FILE1_H_)
```

**main.go**

```
package main

// #cgo pkg-config: python3
// #cgo CFLAGS : -I./ -I/usr/include/python3.6
// #cgo LDFLAGS: -L/usr/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-x86_64-linux-gnu -L/usr/lib -lpython3.6 -lpthread -ldl  -lutil -lm
// #include <Python.h>
import "C"

import "fmt"

func main() {

  cmd := exec.Command("python", "-c", "import network; network.getTable()")
  cmd.Dir = "/home/username/go/src/network"    //directory where is my python code
  out,err := cmd.CombinedOutput()
}
```

After building this main.go, I get the error as

> /usr/include/boost/config/no_tr1/memory.hpp: fatal error: memory: No
> such file or directory
>  >  #  include 
>  >             ^~~~~~~~ > compilation terminated.

How to import .so as Python modules in Go?
Can Swig be used in this place?

What is the better approach to expose Python module to Go?

Comment: Are you trying to compile your C++ with a C compiler?

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica, I used g++

Comment: So, one of the `*.[hc]pp` files has the `#include <memory>` directive, is it?

Comment: I checked the existing c++ source file. No sign of memory header files

Comment: One more thing: your `main.go` merely runs `python` interpreter's _process_ and tells it to load the module `network` then call a function provided by that module, and the whole thing here is to collect the output of that `python` process. I hence fail to see why are you trying to use [`cgo`](https://golang.org/cmd/cgo/) and/or swig as the task appears to be completely unrelated to calling code form a CPython extension from Go; your Go code does nothing more than calling an external process. Why not just build the CPython module "the normal way" and then make sure the python process finds it?

Comment: OK, let's add more context to that `fatal error:` message. Could you please update your question with the full output produced by the whatever thing you has called, and which has failed.

Comment: I just edited my post giving more visibility to the error

Comment: BTW is this the contunuation of [a previous attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66489991)?

Comment: Yes. I missed adding the entire error. I edited my post to show the entire error message upon building the Go file

Comment: @kostix “ Why not just build the CPython module "the normal way" and then make sure the python process finds it?” —- how to implement this ?

Comment: @Amelia, I would ask whoever made the module. If that was you, you should supposedly already known the answer. Also: do you really need to build the module? Your question begins with mentioning `network.so` is already present, and to me, it looks like a dynamically-loadable library ("shared object", hence the extension `.so`) for a Unix-like system.

Comment: I added #include <Python.h>, rebuild the code and the message I see now is   File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'network'.

Answer (score 0):

Issue fixed. The .so placed in /bin and the Go was build and could access the functions under network